# Good optimizer for CPU and memory intensive command line PHP scripts?

Tags: php, eaccelerator, zend-optimizer

I have optimized the scripts at most possible bottlenecks. 
It is difficult to port the code to other language, so that is not a good solution.

are there any opcode generators, optimizers that I can use to optimize the peformance of these continuously running PHP scripts ?

They run from command line, not on apache.

```
/usr/bin/php myBatchProcessor.php
```

Does eaccelerator or Zend optimizer work for command line scripts ? or any other suggestions 
?

Comment: is code parsing being a bottleneck? what are the numbers?

Comment: often is not the code that is slow, **BUT** your script required lots of external resources (eg. mysql, disk write)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP "*optimizers*" are snake oil!**

"Optimizers" were only needed in the *PHP4* era because of inefficiencies in the transformation from PHP source to the bytecode on which Zend Engine 1 ran.  This is no longer an issue in PHP5.  The modern derivatives of the PHP4-era products also perform bytecode caching, which is very helpful.  Be wary of *any* product that claims it can make plain vanilla PHP faster.  Especially for money.

> They run from command line, not on apache.

Normally, as others have done, I'd recommend the APC *bytecode cache*, but APC does nothing for long-running scripts run at the command line.

Are you *sure* that you already [**profiled your code** and removed every possible bottleneck](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler)?

If so, it might be time to take a stab at [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php), a compiler that transforms PHP into C++ before creating an executable.  It might not be suitable for your needs, as it's designed *exclusively* for serving HTTP requests.

Comment: HipHop works wonders, especially on loop or math intensive scripts. It doesn't have to be used for serving HTTP, but can be used to make executable apps. Math & loops will be 10x faster, but functions will be more-or-less the same speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can install APC and enable APC for command line caching. Make sure! to disabled APC for your webserver in that case otherwise the two will clash.

Don't expect **too** much from APC as the opcode generation usually isn't the part that slows your script down, look at profiling your scripts.

*edit:*
Add these settings to your config file:
`apc.enabled = 1

apc.enable_cli = 1`